# How to use javascript in Layout for multiple Views .NET Core?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a javascript code and I need to put it in Layout to use for all my views in .NET Core. I use

```
<script src="~/js/template.js"></script>
```

it works, but only for first page. I tried to use also @Scripts.Render(), but it's an old method from .NET Framework.

Comment: `it works, but only for first page` ← define works and also explain only for the first page.

Comment: if you have added script in `_Layout.cshtml` and you are using `_Layout.cshtml` in all pages then it will work.
you might have to use `app.UseStaticFiles();` inside `startup.cs` before routing.

Comment: There is not enough information to really tell what your exact issue is. You can try replacing `"~/js/template.js"` with `"Url.Content("~/js/template.js")"` to see if it is a path problem with your routing on the other pages. You should also verify your `_ViewStart.cshtml` or each page's view contains a directive for `@{ Layout = "_Layout"; // or whatever layout file you are choosing to use } `.

Comment: I tried every method what you said, Url.Content("~/js/template.js"), UseStaticFiles, but the problem still exist.

Comment: I suggest you give us the content of `template.js` and the content of the current `layout`.

Answer (score 0):

- Create **View** for all page like Layout page, you can use default [_Layout.cshtml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-3.1)  in Shared Folder
- Add link js before end body tag
- Add `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` after your link js
- For use layout use `Layout - 'your layout path'` for your page if use _Layout.cshtml no need this line.
- use end page

  @Section Screipts{

  // between tag script write code

  }